# What does the asterisk mean in const char *src?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I have a small program in C that repeats a given string. But I cannot figure out why the function parameter needs to have an asterisk for const char *src.

Here is my code...

```
char *repeat_str(size_t count, const char *src) {
    int length = strlen(src);
    char* dest = malloc(count * length * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      strcpy(dest + i * length, src);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

When I delete the asterisk as a test, I receive errors saying the asterisk is expected, but I don't understand the explanation as to why.

Comment: `char* dest = malloc(count * length * sizeof(char));` -> `char* dest = malloc(count * length + 1);`

Comment: "*I don't understand the explanation as to why.*" So what do you expect from us if not an explanation?

Comment: The `*` says that `src` is a pointer to `char`. I'd advice you to read your C book from the beginning and not jump in in the middle of the book, that is a very basic concept you have to know.

Comment: You aren't allocating enough memory — or the code you copied isn't allocating enough memory since you don't know what the `*` (designating a pointer) means.

Comment: Don't be too harsh. I'm taking a course where we learn a new language every 3 weeks. I'm trying to remember as much as I can. I see it now though, since src is a string (char), the pointer in the parameter will start at the beginning of that string.

Comment: OT: `strlen(src);` returns a `size_t` not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the formal explanations of the pointer declarators: [6.7.6.1 declarators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.1).

`char *src` is a C convention which says that `src` is a `char pointer`.
In program below it points to the `string literal` holding `4` characters `123_` and string terminator `\0`.
The length of the string is `4`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

// `repeat_str` accepts variable count of type size_t and const char * pointer

char *repeat_str(size_t count, const char *src) {

    size_t length = strlen(src); // get the length

    char* dest = malloc(count * length * sizeof(char) + 1); // you need 1 more character for the `null` termination of the dest string

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      strcpy(dest + i * length, src);
    }

    return dest; // return pointer
}

int main() {

  const char *src =  "123_";  // pointer declaration 
  char *p; // pointer declaration

   p = repeat_str(3,src);

   printf(" %s", p);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 123_123_123_
```

Comment: @slickset If you value my help you could upvote my answer and accept it. I would appreciate it. Thanks!